# Having problem using ls or commands on file: '\' , even escaping with '\\'

Tags: files, delete

Using Windows WSL Bash Subsystem, I have a directory that appears to contain a file: `'\'` .

I am attempting to delete this directory, but cannot.
When I use `ls` in the directory,  I get the output:

```
$ ls
ls: cannot access '\': No such file or directory
'\'
$ ls -li
ls: cannot access '\': No such file or directory
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? '\'
```

Assuming this is an escaped character problem, I have tried:

```
$ rm '\\'
rm: cannot remove '\': No such file or directory
$ rm "\\"
rm: cannot remove '\': No such file or directory
$ rm "./\\"
rm: cannot remove './\': No such file or directory
$ rm './\\'
rm: cannot remove './\\': No such file or directory
$ rm './\'
rm: cannot remove './\': No such file or directory
```

... as well as several iterations from outside the directory in question.

How can I remove this "file" and the directory that (supposedly) contains it?

**Edit:**

This directory is on an external USB disk.

I can rename the directory.

`$ ls -ld` :  returns the entry for "."

Comment: Is this a network share of some sort? Or an external USB disk? What do you get if you `ls -ld {path}`, replacing `{path}` with the full path of the directory you're trying to delete?

Comment: That's not an escaping problem, that's a filesystem broken in one way or another. Note that in the first ones, you didn't enter the file name as a command line argument, so there's nothing to escape. It's just `ls` asking the system for a list of files in the directory, and then that one being impossible to access. It probably isn't about the directory permissions either, since it's already your working directory -- unless the permissions changed after you `cd`'d there.

Comment: run `ls -ld` on the directory itself.

Comment: You seem to have a corrupt filesystem. You may want to unmount it and run `fsck` on it.

Comment: @roaima Yes this is an external USB disk actually.

Comment: This was indeed an NTFS filesystem problem (this system is Ubuntu on Windows), and was fixed by using `chkdsk /f` on windows powershell, thanks! If someone would like to suggest this general "check filesystem" answer, I will accept as answer.

Comment: @Dan if you want the points for the answer, write your own (even as a copy of the Community Wiki answer), and someone will delete the Community Wiki answer in favour of yours

Comment: @roaima Thanks, but I think someone else deserves the  points for pointing me in the right direction! (pun intended only retroactively)

Comment: No-one gets points for a Community Wiki post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a general filesystem problem. Was fixed by using windows powershell `chkdsk \f` which deleted the offending entry.